# Assign median value for each quartile group using loop [R]

Tags: r, loops, group-by, dplyr

I need to categorize numeric variable into the quartile and assign the median values for the quartile groups using loop (because my original dataset has lots of variable).

What I intend is doing the following manipulation over lots of variables:

```
data(iris)
iris%>%mutate(Sepal.Lengthq=as.factor(ntile(Sepal.Length,4)))%>%
  group_by(Sepal.Lengthq)%>%
  mutate(Sepal.Lengthq_median=median(Sepal.Length,na.rm=T))
```

I need loop, so I wrote codes like:

```
quartilization=c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")

for (i in seq_along(quartilization)){
  iris2=iris %>% 
    mutate(!!str_c(quartilization[i],"q"):=ntile(.[[quartilization[i]]],4)) %>% 
    group_by_at(vars(one_of(!!str_c(quartilization[i],"q")))) %>% 
    mutate(!!str_c(quartilization[i],"qn"):=median(.[[quartilization[i]]],na.rm=T)) %>%
    ungroup()
}
```

However, 1) it does not return "Sepal.Lengthqn" and 2) "Sepal.Widthqn" is a same value over samples.

I feel like the syntax for the median function is wrong, but cannot fix it.

So appreciated if anyone could share me some input. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `.`, you refer to entire dataframe, hence you get the same value for all the years. Use `.data` in `median` to get data in the group.

I use `map_dfc` instead of `for` loop because it is easier and shorter. I also use `transmute` instead of `mutate` because `mutate` returns all the column every time whereas `transmute` only returns the changed columns which can be binded to original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

quartilization=c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")

bind_cols(iris, map_dfc(quartilization, ~{
            iris %>%
             group_by(!!str_c(.x,"q") := ntile(.[[.x]],4)) %>%
             transmute(!!str_c(.x,"qn"):= median(.data[[.x]],na.rm=TRUE))
}))
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!!